# Dynamic drop down menu

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to do a dynamic drop down menu. First I read from a sql table some dates and them I want to print the dates in a drop down box and select one. I can print them, but I can't seem to select one. This is my code on the relevant part:

```
    ?>
    <form action="dataProc.php" method="POST">
        <select id="dates" name="dates">                      
            <option value="0">--Selecionar Dia--</option>

            <?php 
                for($i = 0 ; $i < count($resultados) ; $i++)
                {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php $i ?>"><?php echo $resultados[$i]['anoDia'] ;?></option>
                    <?php 
                }
            ?>

        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Escolher">
    </form>
    <?php 

    if(isset($_POST['dates']))
    {
        if(empty($_POST['dates']))
        {
            echo 'ya';
        }
        else
        {
            echo $_POST['dates'].'<br>';
        }
    }
```

EDIT: manage to solve my problem. Just changed `<?php $i ?>` to `<?php echo $resultados[$i]['anoDia'] ;?>`

Comment: How is your `$resultados` array populated?

Comment: `$resultados = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using the specified EDIT